# how can i pass a string from activity to Service in Android?

Tags: android

Can anyone tell how to pass an String or integer whatever, from activity to Service.
im trying to pas an integer setpossition(4), but it doesnt take, always it takes 0 Service when it start I dont know why i cant manipulate from Activity by using an instance of Service.

```
    public class MainMP3 extends Activity{
Button play,stop,prev,next,list;

static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
 Activity main_activity;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    main_activity=this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mp3interface);


    play= (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    stop= (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    prev= (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);
    next= (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    list= (Button) findViewById(R.id.listofsongs);


    play.setOnClickListener(new StartClick());  

    stop.setOnClickListener(new StopClick());  

    prev.setOnClickListener(new PullClick());  





    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override                           
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });


    list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override                           
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i= new Intent(MainMP3.this,songlist.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}




  ServiceMP3 service = null;

  ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override  // Called when connection is made
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName cName, IBinder binder) {
            service = ((ServiceMP3.SlowBinder)binder).getService();
        }
        @Override   //
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName cName) {
            service = null;
        }
    };


    private class StartClick implements View.OnClickListener {      
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(main_activity,ServiceMP3.class);
            service.setposition(4);
            main_activity.startService(intent);



        }
    }

    private class StopClick implements View.OnClickListener {       
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(main_activity,ServiceMP3.class);
            main_activity.stopService(intent);

        }
    }


    private class PullClick implements View.OnClickListener {       
        public void onClick(View v) {



        }
    }


        }
```

Comment: You are creating a ServiceConnection but starting the service with startService() API. Consider using bindService(), and before re-factoring your code, I would highly recommend you to read this article: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the values in intent and pass that intent while starting the service,
and you can get the values in serivce onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId).

This is how you have to pass that integer through intent.

```
private class StartClick implements View.OnClickListener {      
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(main_activity,ServiceMP3.class);
                intent.putExtra("position",4);
                main_activity.startService(intent);

            }
        }
```

You can get the values is service like this

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(intent != null){
       int position = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are just talking about passing data to your `Service`, then here is my solution. When launching a service via `Intent`, put any data you want to pass to the `Service` in the `Bundle`, like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("my_Val", 4);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

And then use the `Intent` like normal. On the other side, in your `Service` just get the data from the `Bundle`:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
int myVal = bundle.getInt("my_Val", 0); //0 is just the default value used in case of error
```

Comment: What is intent in the service? It is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an inner class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` in the activity you want to get your data to:

   ```
   private BroadcastReceiver ReceivefromService = new BroadcastReceiver(){
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
       {
           //get the data using the keys you entered at the service
           String IncomingSms=intent.getStringExtra("incomingSms");//
           String phoneNumber=intent.getStringExtra("incomingPhoneNumber");

       }
   };
   ```
2. Add this to `onPause()`:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       try {
           unregisterReceiver(ReceivefromService);
       } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
           if (e.getMessage().contains("Receiver not registered")) {
               Log.i("TAG","Tried to unregister the reciver when it's not registered");
           }
           else
           {
               throw e;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add this to `onResume()`:

   ```
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       filter.addAction("android.intent.action.SmsReceiver");
       registerReceiver(ReceivefromService, filter);
       //the first parameter is the name of the inner class we created.
   }
   ```
4. Create an intent inside the receiver/service that start the broadcast like this:

   ```
   Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.SmsReceiver").putExtra("incomingSms", message);
   i.putExtra("incomingPhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
   context.sendBroadcast(i);
   ```

and that's it! goodLuck!

Comment: hi can you check also this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64522613/android-bundle-usage