# Get argument in service passed by activity.Media player.Android

Tags: android, service, media-player

please help me.I have an activity class and service class.Activity contain many buttons,so when user click it shows corresponding to button  xml,and it must play corresponding sound.So i pass argument to service via putExtra,but i can't get it in service class.I get it in onStartCommand(),but it doesn't create or play it(so i don't know).How to solve this problem?     Thank you.Here my code.
Activity.java

```
              public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(arg0.getId()==R.id.Button01){
         id=arg0.getId();
        service = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        service.putExtra("ButtonA", id);
                startService(service);

        setContentView(R.layout.button_a);

    }
```

....
Service.java

```
 public void onCreate() {}
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId){
            Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           onHandleCommand(intent);


            return START_STICKY;
            }

    private void onHandleCommand(Intent intent) {

       if(button.equals(intent.getStringExtra("ButtonA"))){
           player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alma);
           player.setLooping(false); 
            } else if(button.equals(intent.getStringExtra("ButtonAE"))){
                player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.azhe);
                 player.setLooping(false); 
            }

    }
```

Comment: Where do you assign button?

Comment: This is:    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
       Button btn2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
       Button btn3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button03);
       Button btn4 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button04);
        btn1.setOnClickListener( this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn4.setOnClickListener( this);

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I missed the point,`onHandleCommand` is your own method and you cannot override it.
Looks like your problem is here :

```
  if(button.equals(intent.getStringExtra("ButtonA")))
```

What you passing as an extra to intent here?
What you are trying to compare?A Button and a String?

Comment: I do so,but it says:The method onHandleCommand(Intent) of type MyService must override or implement a supertype method and - Method breakpoint:MyService [entry] - onHandleCommand(Intent)

Comment: I passing string and int,in this way  service = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        service.putExtra("ButtonA", id);
                startService(service); Above i show my activity class.And here button is a String variable:private String button;

Comment: Thank you for help).Yes I passing string and int, Above i show my activity class.And here button is a String variable:private String button="ButtonA"; Now it shows image but d not play music.i add player.start() to onHandleCommand method after setLooping(false).but it still doesn't play

Comment: thank you!i solve this problem by using Bundle.)))http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370108/how-can-i-pass-a-string-from-activity-to-service-in-android