# Android Bundle usage

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is it possible to use Android `Bundle` to create and  `putString()` in Activity then `getString()` in Service on button click?

If not what can i do?

Example

MainActivity.kt

```
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("MyString", "Message")

        val mesg = Message.obtain(null, MyService.SEND_MESSAGE_FLAG)
        mesg.obj = bundle
        try {
            myService!!.send(mesg)
        } catch (e: RemoteException) {
        }
```

Service

```
override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
        when (msg.what) {
            SEND_MESSAGE_FLAG -> {
                val data = msg.data
                val dataString = data.getString("MyString")
                println(dataString)
                val mesg = Message.obtain(null, SEND_MESSAGE_FLAG)
                mesg.obj = dataString

                try {
                    msg.replyTo.send(mesg)
                } catch (e: RemoteException) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Error: " + e.message)
                }
            }
        }

        super.handleMessage(msg)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add static method in your service:

```
companion object {
    private const val EXTRA_KEY_MY_STR = "EXTRA_KEY_MY_STR"

    fun startMyService(context: Context?, myStr: String?) {
        if (context != null) {
            val intent = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_MY_STR, myStr)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(intent)
            } else {
                context.startService(intent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then call it from your activity: `MyService.startMyService(this, "MyString")`
and then get string in your onHandleIntent(): `val myStr = intent?.extras?.getString(EXTRA_KEY_MY_STR)`

Comment: no i need to pass data on button click before that i'm also starting my service...